# Get content of the directory using wildcast with FileSystemObject

Tags: vba

I'm using Dir function to get directory's content right now.

```
FileSpec = DirPath & "/GenerateID_*_*.zip"
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
```

But Dir function is locking the folder and can't delete that folder until I close my VBA application. I have tried `ChDir("C:\")` to make this point to another directory after calling Dir function but it's not working.

Is it possible to filter using FileSystemObject like Dir function? Or get all files with FileSystemObject, loop each fileName and checking each one would be the only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly loop through the files with the FileSystemObject.  From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306(v=vs.84).aspx) for the `Files` Property of the FileSystemObject:

```vb
Function ShowFileList(folderspec)
   Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
   Set fc = f.Files
   For Each f1 in fc
      s = s & f1.name 
      s = s &   "<BR>"
   Next
   ShowFileList = s
End Function
```

This will return a string that is delimited by '<BR>'.  You can replace this with something else, like `vbCrLf` or whatever you like then parse the string as required.